# Button back in from gives page is not found

Tags: php, html, forms, button

I have a multiform with two buttons on every page. One for going forward and one for going backward. On the second page the back-button works fine but then for all others the browser show me page is not found page.

**code:**

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Formular start -->
    <form id="formular" action="Formular-Haushaltsvollzug.php" method="POST">
        <!-- 3.4. Fallzahlenentwicklungen -->
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"  data-background-color="purple">
                    <h4 class="title">4. Fallzahlenentwicklungen aus den zugeh&ouml;rigen FB (sofern messbar)</h4>
                    <p class="category"></p>
                </div>

                <div class="card-content">
                    <!--4.1-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
                            <div class="form-group label-floating optimaler-abstand">
                                <div class="label">
                                    <label for="Gleitzeitrahmen"> 
                                        <div class="aufzählung">4.1
                                            <div class="material-icons md-24 forminfo" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Sind Fluktuationen im Bereich Personal feststellbar? Wie ist die Situation zum vorigen Quartal zu bewerten? Auch k&uuml;nftige Zu-und Abg&auml;nge k&ouml;nnen hier vermerkt werden. ">info_outline</div>
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="beschreibung">Fallzahlenentwicklungen</div>
                                    </label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="Fallzahlenentwicklungen" name="name_Fallzahlenentwicklungen" rows="1" maxlength="250"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <!--Fallzahlenentwicklungen-->
                        <div style="float:right">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="button" onclick="eingaben_speichern()">Weiter</button>
                        </div>
                        <!--zürück-->
                        <div style="float:right">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="zur&uuml;ck" onclick="history.back()">
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>
    </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: when you hit the back button, it actually tries to resubmit the form. Try to load the page without resubmitting the form. A couple of solutions available simplest one is to force a page reload.

Comment: Can you post your javascript? Off the bat we can see that you're using both a form post (i.e. submit button) and javascript to go back and forth on your site, which is not recommended. Either only use <a>'s and <input type="submit"> or use javascript and Ajax

Comment: @AsitVachhani ok Can you give me more information how to do that?

Comment: @Glubus for the buttons i do not use any javascript. So when I use only inputs it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your back button with following code.

```
<!--zürück-->
<div style="float:right">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="zur&uuml;ck" onclick="location.href = document.referrer;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this works fine! Meanwhile I found out, that there is a very simple solution with bootstrap. Only change the button to a link which has the same style like the button has.

`<a class="btn" href="">Link</a>`